# Composition of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is increasing convex function and $g$ is convex function then $f\circ g$ is also convex function.

But can anyone give a counterexample where $f$ is decreasing convex and $g$ convex but $f\circ g$ is NOT convex?

Comment: $f(x)=-x,g(x)=e^x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, very easy example! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First exampke that comes to mind is, on $(0,\infty) $, $f (x)=1/x $, $g (x)=1/\sqrt x $. Then $f (g (x))=\sqrt x $, not convex.

Comment: Nice example! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$ and $g(x) = x^{-1}$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=x^2$, $f(x)=(\frac{1}{2})^x$. Then $f\circ g (x)=(\frac{1}{2})^{x^2}$ is not convex